# -bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory on remote server

Tags: bash, memory

I have the great `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` error.

Normall I would reboot.  But that is not an option.  Using only SSH can you imagine some trick I can use?  `/sbin/shutdown -r now` gives the error.  `ls` gives the error.  `ps` gives the error.

I think there is nothing to do.  But why not ask?

Comment: Rather than implicitly  fork a subshell to execute a command in you can substitute  your current shell and use `exec` to replace the shell with 1 different command

Comment: Tried that.  No luck.  Actually I am locked out of SSH now so that is the end.  But these are good suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to reboot your server the magic way. First, you must activate the magic SysRq option (if not already activated)

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

When you are ready to reboot the machine simply run the following:

```
# echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Comment: I tried that.  'echo' kicks me out of the shell.  Good idea though!  (And useful for other people with similar problems.